# How to complete the set to the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (vector spaces, subspaces, bases)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi I need to solve next exercise :"Complement the set $(1,0,1),(1,1,0)$ to the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$"

I know that I have to get $(0,1,1)$, but I do not know how.

Comment: Every $3$ linearly independent vectors will form a basis for a $3$ dimensional space. So all you need is to verify that those vectors are linearly independent. What is the problem?

Comment: I dont how to do that, i didnt attend lecture unfortunately :(

Comment: "I know that I have to get $(0,1,1)$" : precisely, this is wrong. This is a possible solution, but there are infinitely many other ones. Do you know what a basis is ?...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe i solved it by finding complement for (1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0). Is this valid?

Answer (score 1):

As some have mentioned before, since the dimension of the space you are considering is three, you only need to find three linearly independent vectors. This is a consequence of the famous [Steinitz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma). How can we find it? You could propose a system of equations and solve it (using, as other users have already mentioned, the definition of a linear combination). Another way in this case is to see that the determinant containing the three vectors is non-zero.

> This is a spoilerFor example, the vectors (1,0,1),(1,1,0),(0,1,0)  work. There are many options.

Comment: Wow, thats sounds great , could you explain it little more, i dont understand it really good, i already solved exercise by finding complement for (1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)

Comment: What is the part that you do not fully understand? Yeah, (1,0,0) also works as it does (0,1,0) or (0,1,1). There are a LOT of choices for the third vector in the basis provided that all of them are linearly independent, following the Steinitz Theorem.